# AWK csv manipulation

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed, csv

I have a csv file containing something like this:

```
abc;!!!!;22
abc;!!!!;23
23;!!!!!;22
```

Now I want to delte every line that contains a 23 in the third column.

Since there is a possibility that there is a 23 in the first one. It should only check for matches in the third column.

I would prefer the awk soloution, since I really want to learn it, but if someone can tell me how to do that with sed, I would be impressed!

It should work similar to this bad example of me.

```
awk -F ";" (if $3="23") delete Line
```

Comment: Would you like the output all columns except the last one?

Comment: There are loads of learning resources about awk right here: all the StackExchange sites are part wiki. Click the [tag:awk] tag, then click the [Learn more…](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/awk/info) link on the awk tag page.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant is "if $3 is different from 23, print it"

```
awk -F';' '$3 != 23' file
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification of your approach might already work (untested):

```
awk -F ";" '$3 ~ /23/ {next} 1' file
```

"contains" means "has, amongst others". If you mean "equals", use the `==`
 operator.

Comment: This would also delete line containing `230` etc. in the third column. Better to use `$3 == 23`.  (oh, didn't see that last line... but anyway)

Comment: @Kusalananda: Thanks, but that was a bit diffuse in the request...

Comment: It is. `230` "contains `23`"...

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
sed '/;23$/d' infile
```

If you can have more than 3 columns

```
sed '/\([^;]*;\)\{2\}23\(;\|$\)/d' infile
```

Or with ERE

```
sed -E '/([^;]*;){2}23(;|$)/d' infile
```